# The jQuery UI Datepicker doesn't Appear

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/
When I use the sourcecode below and paste it into my html file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
```

Date:

The menu doesn't appear.

What is wrong?

Thanks!

I'm aware that `href="/resources/demos/style.css"` doesn't work because I dont have the file

Comment: add an input with id `datepicker` and check again

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work. How about you?

Comment: i will work if you have the input text with the id `datepicker ` can you add the entire html

Comment: It doesn't work in my client computer but when I tried using it by using "http://jsbin.com/luzafecake/edit?html,css,js,output" it works

Comment: I will assume that you have an error in console saying `$ is undefined` include the jquery script

Comment: In local env any error in the network console?

Comment: How should I trouble shooting in this context?

Comment: Have a look at the FIDDLE here http://jsfiddle.net/GoranMottram/8w8v9/

Answer (score 0):

Here is your Solution [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ojzxVL). Check this Out. I think there is only Input Field Problem

```
<input id="datepicker" type="text" name="fname">
```

and function not written in

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
```

It works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $(".datepicker").datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                yearRange: '1800:2100'
            });

        })
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type='text' class='datepicker' />
</body>

</html>
```

`Make sure you include the scripts both of them`

```
<script type="text/javascript"src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

You can download [here](http://jquery.com/download/) and [here](http://blog.jqueryui.com/2014/01/jquery-ui-1-10-4/)